# Keras Multivariate Shape for LSTM

Tags: r, keras, lstm

I am trying to shape the dataframe to be able to to run a LSTM on R.

What I have is 100 list with 4 features and 10 rows per list and I want to predict 100 values.
I have reshape my list into an array try to run the model but got an error similar to this

```
  ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 10
  y sizes: 100
```

I am not to understand what is the shape that I need to apply to my array to be able to make it work

I recreated my problem into a sample of data

```
library("keras")
#creation of the dataframe 

x <- data.frame(
x1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000),
x2 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000),
x3 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000),
x4 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000)
)

y <- data.frame( y = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100))


#transform into list 
x_list <- list()

for(i in 1:100) {
  
  x_list[[i]] <- x[(10*i+1) :((1+i)*10),]  
  
}

#transform into array 

arr_x <- array_reshape(as.numeric(unlist(x_list)), 
               dim = c(dim(x_list[[1]])[1],
                       dim(x_list[[1]])[2],
                       length(x_list) )
)

dim(x_list[[1]])[1]
dim(x_list[[1]])[2]
length(x_list)




lstm_model <- keras_model_sequential()

lstm_model %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 64, 
             input_shape = c(10,4),
             return_sequences = TRUE
  )



lstm_model %>%
  compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = 'binary_crossentropy')

summary(lstm_model)



lstm_model %>% fit(
  x = arr_x,
  y = y,
  batch_size = 1,
  epochs = 20,
  verbose = 0,
  shuffle = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your LSTM Model need an **exact same number of X and Y train sizes**, this is as well as the test sizes if you plan to divide it to Train and Test sets, because it is not making any sense to train a 1000 rows of X (Independent) against 100 rows of response variable Y, **if you want to train dataset against 100 predictors use 100 rows of Independent variable also**

**1 -->** So here I make an update of your sample dataset:

```
x <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000),
  x2 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000),
  x3 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000),
  x4 = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000)
)

y <- data.frame(y = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000))
```

**2 -->** Then, moving to Building LSTM Model Layer and Compile, here I make some modification, I added 1 more Dense Layer after LSTM and `return_sequences` to `FALSE`, Based by my experiences, use `return_sequences=TRUE` if you get to train a deep LSTM Model, and then use `return_sequences=FALSE` to the end of a LSTM Model to return weight to another layer, add `loss` parameter to the compile stage is a mandatory, this will calculate error terms of the model:

```
lstm_model <- keras_model_sequential()

lstm_model %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 64, input_shape = c(4,1), return_sequences = FALSE) %>%
  layer_dense(1, activation="relu")

lstm_model %>%
  compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', 
          metrics = 'binary_accuracy', 
          loss = "binary_crossentropy")
```

**3 -->** And for `x` and `y` to fit into the Model, transform it to Matrix as follows:

```
x_mat <- as.matrix(x)
y_mat <- as.matrix(y)
dim(x_mat) <- c(nrow(x_mat), ncol(x_mat), 1) # Make X (The Independent into 3 Dimensional)

lstm_model %>% fit(
  x = x_mat,
  y = y_mat,
  batch_size = 2,
  validation_split=0.7, #I add this so 700 datasets will be train instead of 1000 (300 will be used as validation (testing datasets))
  epochs = 10,
  verbose = 1,
  shuffle = FALSE
)
```

**4 -->** Then the Model will Start Learning, If you see the accuracy are not really satisfying, Some tips I had noted by myself, is to try to tune it by:

A) Learning Rate parameter in the optimizer parameter, smaller learning rate eg `lr=0.0001` compared by `lr=0.01` are making model to learn more robust predictions

B) Change of a more Efficient Layer based by the dataset Independent and Response distribution

C) If final fit result in to prediction seems to underfitted, try to make more Deep Model rathen than Broad Model

D) Change of Activation Function as for Dense Layer, also helps for some circumstances.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and for the advise on the LSTM model it will definitely help me out. Though it doesn't answer my question it put me on the right direction . I will edit my post and answer my question . In a nutshell the problem is the format of my array reshape should have been c(100,10,4) and not c(10,4,100) . I need to keep 100 as I am doing LSTM with sequential data on a multivariate with 100 samples

Comment: Sure, feel free to reshape your data of your liking. This is a brief of a reproducable example.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Jovan comment I understood how to solve my problem
Basically the shape of my array was defined as 10,4,100 as of this

```
arr_x <- array_reshape(as.numeric(unlist(x_list)), 
               dim = c(dim(x_list[[1]])[1],
                       dim(x_list[[1]])[2],
                       length(x_list) )
)
```

But the array for a multivariate LSTM has to take this shape ( sample , steps, features)

On this case it should be c(100,10,4) as I have 100 of sample , 10 steps and 4 features

```
arr_x <- array_reshape(as.numeric(unlist(x_list)), 
               dim = c(length(x_list) ,
                       dim(x_list[[1]])[1],
                       dim(x_list[[1]])[2] )
)
```